# Is there a standard way of sending GPS navigation over BLE?

Tags: bluetooth, navigation, gps, bluetooth-lowenergy

I'm developing a 'smart watch' which is connected via BLE to an app on a phone.

My idea is to show the direction on the watch so the user doesn't have to remove the phone from their pocket while using their favorite application (Waze, Google Maps, ...)

Is there any standard to send navigation information (turn left/right, ...) to a smart device over BLE?

It seems there are apps that do this, but they are fully custom: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=naAhe7DTKYM. I'm checking on the side of Android Auto, but it seems to me it's only by USB cable.

Comment: The list of Bluetooth specifications are available at: https://www.bluetooth.com/specifications/specs/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Off the top of my head there are two services that you can use for this purpose:-

[Location and Navigation Service](https://www.bluetooth.com/specifications/specs/location-and-navigation-service-1-0/) (Used mostly for outdoor):-

> "The Location and NavigationService(LN Service)exposes location and
> navigation-related data from a Location and Navigation sensor
> (Server)intended for outdoor activity applications."

[Indoor Positioning Service](https://www.bluetooth.com/specifications/specs/indoor-positioning-service-1-0/) (Used mostly for indoor):-

> "The Indoor Positioning Service exposes location information to
> support mobile devices to position themselves in an environment where
> GNSS signals   are not available, for example in indoor premises. The
> location information is mainly exposed via advertising and the
> GATT-based service is primarily intended for configuration."

If both are not 100% suitable for your application, then you can create your custom profile that contains one or both of these services in addition to a custom service (turn left/right etc). This way, any watch can connect to the phone and get the adopted services info, and for any additional info watch can add support for the custom service.

Answer (score 1):

When I was looking for such "standard way" for turn-by-turn navigation (official Bluetooth specification for navigation, similar to official Battery or Heart rate services), I didn't find anything suitable, but I still have a feeling like maybe I've missed something.

Those services Youssif Saeed suggested are for different type of navigation, not turn-by-turn unfortunatery.

Some apps ([Sygic](https://github.com/alexanderlavrushko/BLE-HUD-navigation-ESP32) for example) may integrate their own BLE service.

I guess the application you linked reads notifications (posted by navigation apps like Waze, Google Maps), extract instructions from them, and then send to an external device via BLE.